# Redis Session Storage Issue

Tags: redis

I am a newbie in using Redis as my Cache storage.I am using it to store Cakephp Session in it.But when I store the session in it, It stores them as serialized Json. Now my question is How to store unserialized json in Redis using Cakephp ?

In programming i am able to use the session correctly but when i tried to get the data from cli it gives me something like shown in the update question. I think it is not pure serialized json as when i tried to unserialized it gives me error.

*"s:3141:\"Config|a:1:{s:4:\"time\";i:1533905976;}session_start_time|s:19:\"2018-08-10 18:29:34\";Auth|a:1:{s:4:\"User\";a:19:{s:11:\"merchant_id\";i:16;s:4:\"name\";s:8:\"google\";s:5:\"email\";s:18:\"google@gmail.com\";s:8:\"username\";s:8:\"google\";s:7:\"balance\";s:11:\"92629148.57\";s:22:\"balance_deduction_type\";s:4:\"LIVE\";s:16:\"validate_txn_url\";s:67:\"http://";s:24:\"payment_verification_url\";s:49:\"http://";s:28:\"transaction_notification_url\";s:60:\"http://";s:11:\"sendsms_url\";s:45:\"http://";s:14:\"other_payments\";s:57:\"http://";s:9:\"client_ip\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"created\";O:20:\"Cake\I18n\FrozenTime\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2017-08-04 04:41:55.000000\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:13:\"Asia/Calcutta\";}s:8:\"modified\";N;s:6:\"status\";s:6:\"ACTIVE\";s:4:\"type\";N;s:8:\"tds_rate\";d:0;s:12:\"api_key_hash\";s:32:\"b92c131e5bed70d3b596b1d0f3d7631b\";s:12:\"merchant_ips\";s:66:\"192.168.134.42,127.0.0.1,172.20.2.37,115.249.4.214,192.168.131.253\";}}MR|a:28:{s:11:\"merchant_id\";i:16;s:13:\"merchant_name\";s:8:\"google\";s:17:\"merchant_users_id\";s:6:\"5Adi01\";s:19:\"merchant_user_state\";s:5:\"DELHI\";s:24:\"merchant_user_branchcode\";s:3:\"B01\";s:16:\"merchant_channel\";s:6:\"RETAIL\";s:8:\"services\";s:14:\"GENERAL~HEALTH\";s:6:\"device\";s:7:\"WINDOWS\";s:20:\"merchant_lasttransno\";s:11:\"14507001061\";s:22:\"balance_deduction_type\";s:4:\"LIVE\";s:13:\"merchant_type\";N;s:24:\"payment_verification_url\";s:49:\"http:";s:7:\"sms_url\";s:45:\"http://";s:28:\"transaction_notification_url\";s:60:\"http:";s:16:\"validate_txn_url\";s:67:\"http://";s:14:\"other_payments\";s:57:\"http://";s:8:\"tds_rate\";d:0;s:10:\"retPanName\";s:13:\"PRITESH KUMAR\";s:5:\"rname\";s:19:\"Demo id 1 of Aditya\";s:8:\"rphoneno\";s:10:\"9654382580\";s:10:\"retEmailId\";s:27:\"satyendra.jain@skilrock.com\";s:10:\"retAddress\";s:74:\"K-230,VILLAGE KARAWAL NAGAR, Karawal Nagar, EAST DELHIDELHI, India, 110094\";s:14:\"retAddresscity\";s:10:\"EAST DELHI\";s:10:\"retStateId\";s:1:\"5\";s:16:\"diskSerialNumber\";s:22:\"pwdt-web-1332130123428\";s:11:\"merchantids\";s:13:\"5Adi01,5Adi01\";s:10:\"req_params\";a:21:{s:8:\"username\";s:8:\"google\";s:8:\"password\";s:8:\"12345678\";s:12:\"retailercode\";s:6:\"5Adi01\";s:5:\"state\";s:5:\"DELHI\";s:7:\"transno\";s:11:\"14507001061\";s:8:\"checksum\";s:9:\"962335274\";s:7:\"channel\";s:6:\"retail\";s:5:\"rname\";s:19:\"Demo id 1 of Aditya\";s:7:\"phoneno\";s:10:\"9654382580\";s:6:\"device\";s:7:\"WINDOWS\";s:7:\"service\";s:14:\"GENERAL~HEALTH\";s:7:\"product\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"merchantids\";s:13:\"5Adi01,5Adi01\";s:12:\"diskserialno\";s:22:\"pwdt-web-1332130123428\";s:5:\"brand\";s:2:\"PW\";s:8:\"google\";s:9:\"insurance\";s:11:\"countercode\";s:6:\"5Adi01\";s:9:\"machineid\";s:9:\"BECZPULLS\";s:12:\"pw_sessionid\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"apptype\";s:4:\"RPOS\";s:6:\"appver\";s:4:\"3.25\";}s:8:\"products\";s:0:\"\";}\";"*

Comment: JSON is a serialization format. There is no "unserialized JSON".

Comment: why you want to store it using unserialized json , - its left to redis how it will store  internally , your getter method should be able to unserialize it

Comment: @MaheshHegde In programming i am able to use the session correctly but when i tried to get the data from cli it gives me something like shown in the update question. I think it is not pure serialized json as when i tried to unserialized it gives me error.